# Converting .docx to html

Tags: c#, html, ms-word

I want to convert .docx file to .html. I work in C#. My code is this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
        Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        wordDoc = word.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        word.Visible = false;
        Object filepath = @"C:\Users\John\Desktop\begin.docx";
        Object confirmconversion = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Object readOnly = false;
        Object saveto = @"C:\Users\John\Desktop\result.html";
        Object oallowsubstitution = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        wordDoc = word.Documents.Open(ref filepath, ref confirmconversion, ref readOnly, ref oMissing,
                                      ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                      ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                      ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML;
        wordDoc.SaveAs(ref saveto, ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                       ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                       ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oallowsubstitution, ref oMissing,
                       ref oMissing);
```

The problem is, this doesn't include the header and the footer. They aren't in the .html result file. How can I include them in the result?

Comment: have you tried doing that manually? I mean saving to HTML from Word. Does it include header and footer?

Comment: Yes, I've tried and it doesn't.

Comment: Is a (commercial) library an option ?

Comment: Yes, but I've already tried many.

Comment: The problem is that a Word document consists of pages (with headers and footers) and an HTML file is just a single page - no place for headers/footers.

Comment: Yes, but the client says he needs the html to be 100% the same as the .docx files. So, the header and the footer must be included.

Comment: So, your client wants a multiple page document to be converted into a single page document, and also wants it to look *100% the same*? Does this seem possible? Can your client provide a simple docx/html tuple (written manually, for example), to demonstrate how this should look like? On the other hand, is there a reason why you would go for HTML? It's not a suitable format for printing at all. Consider RTF, if you want a more accessible replacement. Or PDF, as @hype8912 said below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see the headers and footers in Word is because you are basically in a Print view. In an HTML document you are in a "Draft" style view where headers and footers do not exist. You can setup a different style for your HTML document for when it is printed called a [print stylesheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20111128074859/http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml). This print stylesheet is only used when you print the document in the browser.

Another option would be to just convert it to a PDF and allow the user's to view the PDF since most browsers now either support PDF viewing or have a plugin to support it.

You could also add the headers and footers to the html file as an element and then use some CSS trickery to make the elements display at the top and bottom. [Here is a link](https://web.archive.org/web/20121228173037/http://www.noobcube.com/tutorials/html-css/fixed-header-footer-layout-a-beginners-guide-/) describing how to do this.

[2]: Old link redirected to a Russian site asking for a phone number with "Telegram" branding. now changed to web archive of 2012 content