# How to convert a DocX into HTML using C#

Tags: c#, .net

```
 static void Main(string[] args)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine("\tImagesTables()");  

        // Create a document.  
        using (DocX document = DocX.Create(@"Sample.docx"))  
        {  
            // Add a hyperlink into the document.  
            Novacode.Hyperlink link = document.AddHyperlink("link", new Uri("http://www.google.com"));  
            // Add a Table into the document.  
            Novacode.Table table = document.AddTable(2, 2);  
            //table.Design = TableDesign.ColorfulGridAccent2;  
            table.Design = TableDesign.ColorfulList;  
            table.Alignment = Alignment.center;  
            table.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs[0].Append("1");  
            table.Rows[0].Cells[1].Paragraphs[0].Append("2");  
            table.Rows[1].Cells[0].Paragraphs[0].Append("3");  
            Row newRow = table.InsertRow(table.Rows[1]);  
            //Insert a new Paragraph into the document.  
            Paragraph title = document.InsertParagraph().Append("DocX word document").FontSize(20).Font(new FontFamily("Arial"));  
            title.Alignment = Alignment.center;  
            // Insert a new Paragraph into the document.  
            Paragraph p1 = document.InsertParagraph();  
            // Append content to the Paragraph   
            p1.AppendLine("Here is a URL ").AppendHyperlink(link).Append(".");  
            p1.AppendLine("This line contains a ").Append("word").Bold().Append(" in bold.");  
            p1.AppendLine();  
            p1.AppendLine("Here is a Table");  
            p1.AppendLine();  
            // Insert the Table after Paragraph 1.  
            p1.InsertTableAfterSelf(table);  
            // Save this document.  
            document.Save();  
            Document doc = new Document();  
            doc.LoadFromFile("Sample.docx");  
            doc.SaveToFile("toPDF.PDF", FileFormat.PDF);   
            Console.WriteLine("\tCreated: docs\\HyperlinksImagesTables.docx\n");    
        }  
    }
```

> The above code works good for converting DocX to PDF.
>
> Ways of converting Is there efficient code for the above code But can
>   I convert DocX to HTML or text file
>
> Can somebody help out with my question? Thank in advance!

Comment: Hi, your question is unclear, can you paraphrase it a bit?

Comment: My question is that can I get a c# code for converting Docx to HTML or Text format? Can you help me out please as am I new to programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting .docx to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135901/converting-docx-to-html)

Comment: Yes it seems to be similar bit complex and in that I can find converting to HTML only.

Comment: You can also probably find article under `converting docx to text C#` or `converting html to text C#`, use your google-fu

Comment: Thanks for your response bro.

Comment: Have you checked which Formats there are in the `FileFormat` enum? Maybe that lib can do it already. You would just have to specify html or txt format in the `doc.SaveToFile(... ` line.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer

Comment: Found helpful https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/65794e/using-spire-doc-introduction/